# XPS to Word 2007

Tags: vb.net, xps, word-2007, xpsdocument, wordprocessingml

Is there a way to convert XPS to Word or RTF using VB.NET?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this should be possible as xps is an xml based vector mark-up. It would be a hard task though to write yourself, unless you work in this area allot though. 
I would suggest that you look for a tool to do it for you. such as

http://www.investintech.com/xpscentral/xpstoword/

Looking at this you may have to write some automation in VB.net

even the tools vary in the job they do translating the styles etc.

marcus

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. It's hard work as 76 states, but it would basically be using Linq-to-XML or XSLT to transform XPS to WordprocessingML. [This series](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/archive/2008/10/20/eric-white-s-blog-s-table-of-contents.aspx#Open_XML_XHtml) is A) in C# and B) for WML to XHTML, but the principles of transformation are the same.

XPS's XML is one form of XAML, so if you're familiar with XAML in WPF or Silverlight, you should feel close to home with this XAML - you can read more about it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/xps/default.mspx).